# Counting occurrences of a specific element in list after a character in Prolog?

Tags: prolog, find-occurrences

So with this code I believe I'm quite close but I think I messed it up when trying to count '`w`' in a list only after a '`b`' and not before. For example `h1([w,w,b,w,b,b],H)` would succeed with `H=1`.

EDIT: I believe my base cases are correct. But the recursion is wrong in the second part.

```
h1([], 0).
h1([b|T], Count) :-
    h1(T, TCount),
    Count is TCount + 1.
```

I feel like I'm close to it. P.S. the "" are there because I'm unsure what to put there yet trying some things at the moment.

```
h1([H|T], Count) :-
    "" \== H,
h1(T, Count).
```

Comment: The second part?

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is step through every element in the list, check whether it's your condition character, then count the elements and return that to your call.

```
forFirstBCountW(List, Count) :- detect_b(List, Count).

detect_b([], _).
detect_b([b|T], Count) :- count_w(T, 0, Count), !.
detect_b([_|T], Count) :- detect_b(T, Count).

count_w([], TotalCount, TotalCount) :- !.
count_w([w|T], CurrentCount, TotalCount) :- 
   NewCount is CurrentCount + 1,
   count_w(T, NewCount, TotalCount).
count_w([_|T], NewCount, TotalCount) :- 
   count_w(T, NewCount, TotalCount).
```

I can really recommend reading [Learn Prolog Now!](http://www.learnprolognow.org/lpnpage.php?pageid=top) to learn the concepts behind Prolog, it's an amazingly powerful language.

EDIT: Separated the predicates for clarity, so that they can be reused individually as `detect_b` wasn't clearly named for what it did. I'm leaving the old program in there so you can compare how they get to the same result, while taking different paths:

```
forFirstBCountW(List, Count) :- 
   detect_b(List, ListFromB), 
   count_w(ListFromB, 0, Count),
   !.

detect_b([], []).
detect_b([b|T], T) :- !.
detect_b([_|T], ReturnList) :- detect_b(T, ReturnList).

count_w([], TotalCount, TotalCount) :- !.
count_w([w|T], CurrentCount, TotalCount) :- 
   NewCount is CurrentCount + 1,
   count_w(T, NewCount, TotalCount).
count_w([_|T], NewCount, TotalCount) :- 
   count_w(T, NewCount, TotalCount).
```

This could be abstracted even further, which is why Prolog is so fun:

```
forFirstBCountW(List, Count) :- 
   splitListOnChar(b, List, ListFromB), 
   count_Char(w, ListFromB, 0, Count), 
   !.

splitListOnChar(_, [], []).
splitListOnChar(Char, [Char|T], T) :- !.
splitListOnChar(Char, [_|T], ReturnList) :- 
   splitListOnChar(Char, T, ReturnList).

count_Char(_, [], TotalCount, TotalCount) :- !.
count_Char(Char, [Char|T], CurrentCount, TotalCount) :- 
   NewCount is CurrentCount + 1,
   count_Char(Char, T, NewCount, TotalCount).
count_Char(Char, [_|T], NewCount, TotalCount) :- 
   count_Char(Char, T, NewCount, TotalCount).
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll check it out. I see now the recursion that was missing. Especially with the detect b part which I was confused on.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is not 'Prolog'. You may need to read some basic documents to learn more about prolog syntax.

Cause prolog does not use loop but recursion, I suggest a very intuitively recursive thinking:

- Base case: empty list
- Base case: b is the head of the list then just count no. of w for the rest of the list.
- Recursive case: b is not the head then just call the function for the rest of the list.

I am quite sure there are other elegant ways to solve this problem. Have fun.

Comment: I think I know what you mean. I edited what I originally had and was trying something new but obviously that failed. I think I got my base cases straight in this new edit but am missing something

Comment: Wait, doesn't this base case count every letter after 'b' at the head of the list? ... Which wouldn't be right for [b,w,b,b] which would say H=3? Hmm maybe I was wrong about my base

Comment: First base case: an empty list is clear and you get it right. Second base case: "just count no. of w for **the rest** of the list", supposes you have a support function that just counts a number of 'w' in the list (simpler problem than yours but a good practice).

Comment: I think I know what you mean. I have an occurrence function from a different program I was working on that can count how many times an item in the list appears. I was actually trying to use that and tweak to fit this but, as you can see didn't go as plan haha. I'll show that above